# Check if last value after the dash (-) is a number in a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to Check if last value after the dash (-) is a number in a string in PHP, if its a number then remove the value from last dash (-).

Here is how my string looks like:

`about-us-1` or it might looks like `about-us-new` but i just want to trim only `about-us-1` because it have a numeric value in last after dash.

And here is how my PHP function looks like:

```
public static function checkSlug($modelName, $id, $inputSlug = null){
            $i =1;
            $rows = self::getAllRow($modelName, $id);
            foreach($rows as $row){
                if($inputSlug == $row['slug']){
                    $inputSlug = $inputSlug."-".$i;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            return $inputSlug;
        }
```

What it currently do is it adds a new number after `-` like this `about-us-1-2`

Looking for short and simple technique to fix this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this line:

```
$inputSlug = $inputSlug."-".$i;
```

to this:

```
$inputSlug = preg_replace('/-\d+$/', '', $inputSlug) . "-" . $i;
```

`preg_replace('/-\d+$/', '', $inputSlug)` will remove hyphen and trailing digits from input string if present.

Comment: That is regex which matches `-` followed by 1 or more digits followed by end of line anchor.

Comment: What if i wanted to remove the first dash and before first dash value. What could be the regular expression in that case?

Comment: That would be: `$inputSlug = preg_replace('/^[^-]*-/', '', $inputSlug);`

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_replace()

```
<?php
$string = 'about-us-1';
$string = preg_replace('/-[0-9]*$/', '', $string);
echo $string; // about-us
?>
```

Comment: @user3201500, thanks. anubhava's answer is better than me.

Comment: Yes thanks for your recommendation :) I am really glad it can be solved with one expression.